# Spark Streaming doesn't scale with very simple code

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a very simple Spark Streaming code that reads from Kafka and outputs to S3 files:

```java
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                              LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                              ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams))
          .map(...)
          .filter(...)
          .map(...)
          .window(Durations.seconds(windowDuration), Durations.seconds(slideDuration))
          .flatMap(...)
          .map(x -> "") // so that it writes empty strings to mimimize disk writing
          .dstream(...)
          .saveAsTextFiles(...);
```

I tested this on Amazon EMR, with `m3.xlarge` instances, each has 4 vCPUs and 15GB memory, all of them configured with `maximizeResourceAllocation` so they will use all of their 8 YARN cores. Batch interval, window size and slide duration all set to 8 seconds. The table below summarizes the throughput from each configuration:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| # slaves | # vpus | # YARN cores | # Kafka partitions | maxRatePerPartition | events/s |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2        | 8      | 16           | 64                 | 790                 | 50560    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4        | 16     | 32           | 64                 | 1570                | 100480   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 8        | 32     | 64           | 64                 | 2850                | 182400   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 16       | 64     | 128          | 128                | 1680                | 215040   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, everything looks good up to 8 nodes. I changed the number of Kafka partitions to 128 for the 16-node configuration in order to allocate 1 Kafka receiver per executor (the Kafka topic was recreated). The throughput of 16 nodes is only slightly higher than that of 8 nodes. I have no idea what's wrong as the code contains no shuffling nor repartitioning.

Comment: How is the load generated?

Comment: Events are generated from a template with random data filled in, distributed among Kafka partitions in round-robin fashion.